# get text from <span> with beautiful soup

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I want to get text from span tag but i have such problems. 
I wrote this,

```
import bs4 as bs
import urllib.request

page = urllib.request.urlopen('http://www.accuweather.com/en/az/baku/27103/current-weather/27103').read()

soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')

print(soup.find_all('li', class_='wind'))
```

and it returned like that `[<li class="wind"><strong>28 km/h</strong></li>]`

but I want to get just "28 km/h"

then I tried that

```
page = urllib.request.urlopen('http://www.accuweather.com/en/az/baku/27103/current-weather/27103').read()

soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')

print(soup.find_all("span" , { "class" : "wind" }))
```

but it did not work either. Please help me with it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `.find()` and not `.find_all()` to get a *single element* and call `.get_text()` to get the text of the desired element:

```
print(soup.find('li', class_='wind').get_text())
```

Or, you can also use `.select_one()` and locate the same element using a *CSS selector*:

```
print(soup.select_one('li.wind').get_text())
```

---

As a side note, look up the ["AccuWeather API"](http://apidev.accuweather.com/developers/) - that might be a faster, easier and a more appropriate way to get to the desired data.

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot. You can't know how you helped me :) and thanks for advise too. By the way, soup.select_one worked, soup.find did not